# Python dictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have an input dictionary, I want to compare keys with another dictionary and if the key in the lookup dict gets hit, I want it to run a function as the value in the lookup dict.

The function in the look up dict will return a key, value pair that needs to be "updated" into a new dict. So here is an example:

```
out = {getattr(self,self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k:query[k]}) for k in query.keys() if k not in self.exclusions}
```

The result of

```
getattr(self,self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k:query[k]})
```

Is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'new_key':'new_val'}
```

In the comprehension I am getting

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Because it is expecting a key value pair.

Now I can just run a regular loop and an if statement, but I've become kind of adverse to those. Any workaround here?

TLDR:
Dictionary comprehensions, how to insert a dict like this:

```
{{'k':'v'} for k in blahblah}
```

and make k the key and v a value. Note that the dict is returned from a function that gets ran in the expression.

Comment: You have a **set** comprehension; you only have the one expression, not key-value pairs. What expression produces the key, and what produces the value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension expects separate `key` and `value` expressions:

```
{key_expr: value_expr for iterable [more if and for parts]}
```

but if your function produces both, you'd be better of using a `dict()` function with loop:

```
out = dict(getattr(self, self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k: query[k]})
           for k in query if k not in self.exclusions)
```

because that function takes a sequence of *tuples* each containing a key-value pair.

Note that the `.keys()` call is not needed here; iteration directly over `query` is enough to yield keys. You could use set intersections here instead; the `dict.keys()` object is a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) that *itself acts as a set*:

```
out = dict(getattr(self, self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k: query[k]})
           for k in query.keys() - self.exclusions)
```

where the `query.keys() - self.exclusions` expression produces a set of keys that are in `query` but not in the iterable (set, dict, list, tuple, etc.) `self.exclusions`.

If the `self.LOOKUPDICT` values map to attributes on `self`, it could be useful to directly reach into the instance dictionary with:

```
attrs = vars(self)
out = dict(attrs[self.LOOKUPDICT[k]]({k: query[k]})
           for k in query.keys() - self.exclusions)
```

Comment: I agree the `.keys()` is almost never needed, but sometimes it helps with "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: @PeteCacioppi: It creates an extra object you don't need, and for that reason the Python styleguide (as well as the Google styleguide) advice against using it.

Comment: @PeteCacioppi: in Python 2 it creates a new list object containing all the keys, which when used just for iteration is even more overkill.

Comment: @PeteCacioppi: last but not least the `dict` type documentation [explicitly documents `iter(d)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: yes yes and yes. but the style guide also says "I'm just a guide". We're not talking about abusing the self and underscore conventions, just weighing unneeded computation time against the readability of the expected audience.

Comment: @PeteCacioppi: the expected audience here includes Python beginners that'll make the mistake of using `for key in dictionary.keys():` *in Python 2* over and over again. This one is important, you should *always* use `for key in dictionary:`.

Comment: This was a work in progress for me, I was going to clean it up later, I promise ;) Keys help to identify it as a dict too, so when I am looking at it, I don't have to go back in the code and figure out what it is.

Comment: Thanks man, this is pretty kick ass. I should have been able to think of this myself....

Comment: "Keys help to identify it as a dict too, so when I am looking at it, I don't have to go back in the code and figure out what it is." I think that's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

`out = {_k:_v for k in query.keys() for _k,_v in 
        getattr(self,self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k:query[k]}).items() 
        if k not in self.exclusions}`

although this one is probably more what you're after

`out = {_k:_v for k in set(query.keys()).difference(self.exclusions) 
        for _k,_v in  getattr(self,self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k:query[k]}).items()}`

the second one is better because it won't do the `getattr(self,self.LOOKUPDICT[k])({k:query[k]})` call for the `exclusions`